# VBA datepart() function compile error "Expected: Expression"

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, datepart

ok sorry having a grey moment ... the second parameter of the datepart function is causing me grief

passing in a #date# works but not really useful as this is a fixed value ... however, this suggests that the datepart function requires a "date" type

so why doesn't

passing in date() or now() work

variations of
cdate(date())
or
date() as date

don't appear to work?

What am I missing?

I am trying to determine if a record exists in the current year using the following

```
    if not isnull(dlookup("[somefield]","sometable",
                          "[atestfield] = '" & sometestvariable & "' 
                          and
                          datepart('yyyy',[recordDate]) = datepart('yyyy',date())"
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so I have to blame bouncing around various languages ... the issue here is the 'yyyy' ... vba is not liking the single quote because the single quote is used for inline comments